# How to Extend Craft CMS frontend controller?

Tags: controller, yii, extends

How to extend `craft`'s front end controllers?
I don't want to use `twig`.
I like twig but I don't want to use it in `craft`.

Respect my decision and help me.

Is there a good way to do that?. So I can render using my own `views` file. So I can use it like in `Yii`:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $entryData = null; //get the entry data here

    return $this->render('view', [
        'entryData' => $entryData,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Respect the decision but can I ask why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimented a short while ago on how to do it via a custom module, which I think is cleaner than messing around with craft's own stuff.

(Spoiler: It's faster than twig, but not that much)

You have to do your own routing though.

Example:
config/routes.php

```
'demoview' => 'main/demo/demo-view',
'demoentry/<slug:[^\/].*>' => 'main/demo/demo-entry'
```

modules/main/controllers/DemoController.php

```
protected $allowAnonymous = true;

public $layout = 'main';

public function actionDemoView(): string
{
    return $this->render('demoview', [           
        'entries' => Entry::find()
            ->orderBy('title')
            ->all()
    ]);
}

public function actionDemoEntry($slug)
{
    $entry = Entry::find()->slug($slug)->one();
    if (!$entry) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    return $this->render('demoentry', [
            'entry' => $entry
        ]
    );
}
```

Views:

modules/main/views/demo/demoview.php
modules/main/views/demo/demoentry.php
modules/main/views/layouts/main.php

Use a behavior instead of $entry->url, e.g.

```
public function getDemoUrl()
{
    return UrlHelper::siteUrl("/demoentry/{$this->owner->slug}");
}
```

Comment: Thank for your response but nothing has changed. I'm new to craft.

Comment: what class should DemoController extend?

Comment: Besides handling content via craft\elements\Entry there is nothing Craft specific here, all pure Yii2 (see routing/views/behaviors there). The controller extends either yii\web\Controller or craft\web\Controller (better control who can access the actions)